# Unable to exit this illegal statement exception loop

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am new to android.And i got this task at work.you can see in the logs i am getting illegal statement multiple times.what i want is it should give this exception only one time .below is the method that i think causing the exception.

```
   @Override
    public boolean executeInsertQuery(String query) {
        boolean isInsertSuccess;
        SQLiteStatement sqlStmt = null;
        try {
            if (dbWriteInstance == null) {
                dbWriteInstance = getWriteableDatabase();
            }
            sqlStmt = dbWriteInstance.compileStatement(query);
            sqlStmt.executeInsert();
            dbWriteInstance.yieldIfContendedSafely();
            isInsertSuccess = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            bllLog.logInfo(LogWarningEvent.UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION, e,
                    "Exception in SQLiteAccess.executeInsertQuery()");
            isInsertSuccess = false;
        } finally {
            if (sqlStmt != null) {
                sqlStmt.close();
            }
        }

        return isInsertSuccess;
    }
```

```
    /**
     * Compiles an SQL statement into a reusable pre-compiled statement object.
     * The parameters are identical to {@link #execSQL(String)}. You may put ?s in the
     * statement and fill in those values with {@link SQLiteProgram#bindString}
     * and {@link SQLiteProgram#bindLong} each time you want to run the
     * statement. Statements may not return result sets larger than 1x1.
     *
     * @param sql The raw SQL statement, may contain ? for unknown values to be
     *            bound later.
     *
     * @return A pre-compiled {@link SQLiteStatement} object. Note that
     * {@link SQLiteStatement}s are not synchronized, see the documentation for more details.
     *
     * @throws SQLException If the SQL string is invalid for some reason
     * @throws IllegalStateException if the database is not open
     */
    public SQLiteStatement compileStatement(String sql) throws SQLException {
        lock();
        try {
            if (!isOpen()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("database not open");
            }
            return new SQLiteStatement(this, sql);
        } finally {
            unlock();
        }
    }
```

See the image from 10689 to 10715 i am getting this multiple times i just want this whole block one time

[image]

Any suggestion on this will be helpful thanks..

Comment: I don't see any loop

Comment: Hi @Bentaye stackoverflow is not allowing me to share image so i am sharing this image link for the log file https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm6qU.png

Comment: You are probably getting this message once every time `executeInsertQuery` is called. I don't see any problem with that. I think there is not enough information in your question.

Comment: @Bentaye One more thing due to this exception device is stuck in power off activity.how can we avoid this?

Comment: Well, the best way to not have this exception is to fix the issue with the DB. Is that what you are asking? how to fix the DB access?

Comment: @Bentaye Yes. the name of the class is also sqliteDBAccess.stackoverflow is not allowing me to comment more. is their any way you can create a chat room so that we can discuss this briefly?

Comment: I am not an android developer and I am just trying to clarify the question. I can't really help you. Have a try googling `java sqlite "database not open"`  you might have not called the method to open or create the database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes @Bentaye the name of this class is also sqlitedbaccess.sry stack overflow is not allowing me to comment more.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).